# C# Linq to Entities method to project property to string

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, projection

I am trying to refactor a line of code that is used all over the place.  We are using EF6.1 and want to find the phone and email (as strings).

```
    public SiteLabelDto[] GetVendorSites(int vendorId)
    {
        return Context.Sites.Where(s => !s.IsDeleted && s.Vendor.Id == vendorId)
            .Select(s => new SiteLabelDto
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                Name = s.Name,                    
                Address = s.Address.StreetAddress + ", " + s.Address.Locality + ", " + s.Address.Region + ", " + s.Address.Postcode,
                Country = s.Address.Country.Name,
                Email = s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Email) != null ? s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Email).Value : "",
                Phone = s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Phone) != null ? s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Phone).Value : "",                    
            }).ToArray();
    }
```

The code above takes the list of contactpoints and  tries to find the best fit for each type.

```
public class ContactPointEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ContactPointType Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

The method will be extended to try to return the IsDefault one first in the first as well.

My goal it to try and be able to put this into a method or extension so that I can say s.GetcontactPoint(ContactPointType.Email) or s.contactPoints.GetPoints(ContactPointType.Email) and return the string value, or return a contactpoint class if the string is not a possible situation.

The more I read about it, I think I will need to build some expression tree, not sure how yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build an expression tree.

First, since you need to introduce `IsDefault` condition, the expression could look like:

```
s.ContactPoints
 .Where(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Email && x.IsDefault)
 .Select(x => x.Value)
 .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
 .FirstOrDefault()
```

Then, convert the contact point selector into an expression.

```
private static Expression<Func<Site, string>> GetContactPoint(ParameterExpression siteParam, ParameterExpression cpeParam, ContactPointType type)
{
    // Where.
    var typeCondition = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(cpeParam, "Type"), Expression.Constant(type));
    var defaultCondition = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(cpeParam, "IsDefault"), Expression.Constant(true));
    var condition = Expression.AndAlso(typeCondition, defaultCondition);
    var predicateExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<ContactPointEntity, bool>>(condition, cpeParam);
    var whereExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Where", new[] { typeof(ContactPointEntity) }, Expression.Property(siteParam, "ContactPoints"), predicateExp);

    // Select.
    var valueExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<ContactPointEntity, string>>(Expression.Property(cpeParam, "Value"), cpeParam);
    var selectExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { typeof(ContactPointEntity), typeof(string) }, whereExp, valueExp);

    // DefaultIfEmpty.
    var defaultIfEmptyExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "DefaultIfEmpty", new[] { typeof(string) }, selectExp, Expression.Constant(string.Empty));

    // FirstOrDefault.
    var firstOrDefaultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new[] { typeof(string) }, defaultIfEmptyExp);

    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Site, string>>(firstOrDefaultExp, siteParam);
    return selector;
}
```

And also create the site label dto selector.

```
private static Expression<Func<Site, SiteLabelDto>> GetSite(ParameterExpression siteParam, ParameterExpression cpeParam)
{
    var newExp = Expression.New(typeof(SiteLabelDto));
    var initExp = Expression.MemberInit(
        newExp,
        Expression.Bind(typeof(SiteLabelDto).GetProperty("Id"), Expression.Lambda<Func<Site, int>>(Expression.Property(siteParam, "Id"), siteParam).Body),
        Expression.Bind(typeof(SiteLabelDto).GetProperty("Name"), Expression.Lambda<Func<Site, string>>(Expression.Property(siteParam, "Name"), siteParam).Body),
        /* other basic information */
        Expression.Bind(typeof(SiteLabelDto).GetProperty("Email"), GetContactPoint(siteParam, cpeParam, ContactPointType.Email).Body),
        Expression.Bind(typeof(SiteLabelDto).GetProperty("Phone"), GetContactPoint(siteParam, cpeParam, ContactPointType.Phone).Body)
        /* other types */
    );
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Site, SiteLabelDto>>(initExp, siteParam);
    return selector;
}
```

Usage.

```
var siteParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Site), "s");
var cpeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ContactPointEntity), "cpe");
var selector = GetSite(siteParam, cpeParam);
return Context.Sites
    .Where(s => !s.IsDeleted && s.Vendor.Id == vendorId)
    .Select(selector)
    .ToArray();
```

PS:

Probably some code above need to be refactored, this just gives the basic idea how to do it.

**update**

You can also create a wrapper class to contain the EF instance together with all contact points.

```
public class ContactPointExt<T>
{
    public T Instance { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the `GetSite` into `GetContactPoints` to return the result as `ContactPointExt<T>`.

```
private static Expression<Func<Site, ContactPointExt<T>>> GetContactPoints<T>(ParameterExpression siteParam, ParameterExpression cpeParam)
{
    var type = typeof(ContactPointExt<T>);
    var newExp = Expression.New(type);
    var initExp = Expression.MemberInit(
        newExp,
        Expression.Bind(type.GetProperty("Instance"), siteParam),
        Expression.Bind(type.GetProperty("Email"), GetContactPoint(siteParam, cpeParam, ContactPointType.Email).Body),
        Expression.Bind(type.GetProperty("Phone"), GetContactPoint(siteParam, cpeParam, ContactPointType.Phone).Body)
    );
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Site, ContactPointExt<T>>>(initExp, siteParam);
    return selector;
}
```

The result of `ContactPointExt<T>` can be re-projected into `SiteLabelDto` with another `Select`.

```
var siteParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Site), "s");
var cpeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ContactPointEntity), "cpe");
var selector = GetContactPoints<Site>(siteParam, cpeParam);
return Context.Sites
    .Where(s => !s.IsDeleted && s.Vendor.Id == vendorId)
    .Select(selector)
    .Select(s => new SiteLabelDto
    {
        Id = s.Instance.Id,
        Name = s.Instance.Name,
        Email = s.Email,
        Phone = s.Phone
    })
    .ToArray();
```

**EDIT from OP**

we created a wrapper method to make this a little bit simpler to reuse, putting it here just to show others:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps up a each of a query's objects in a ContactPointExt&lt;T&gt; object, providing the default contact point of each type.
    /// The original query object is accessed via the "Instance" property on each result.
    /// Assumes that the query object type has a property called ContactPoints - if different, supply the property name as the first argument.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    /// <param name="contactPointsPropertyName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IQueryable<ContactPointExt<T>> WithContactPointProcessing<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string contactPointsPropertyName = "ContactPoints") where T : class
    {
        var siteParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "s");
        var cpeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ContactPointEntity), "cpe");
        var selector = ContactPointHelpers.GetContactPoints<T>(siteParam, cpeParam, contactPointsPropertyName);
        return query.Select(selector);
    }
```

Comment: I do like your answer, but I need to do this just on the contactpoints,so that it can be reused without having to do the site as an expression tree as well, as this would mean having to do a lot of our repo layer as expression tress. But the answer is close.  I am not sure if it is posisble to "rejig" the getcontactpoint expression method to be just used on the contactpoints as how would you pass the select expression to them all at that point.  I would have thought that if I did s.contactpoints.select(exp()) it would only work on the individual contactpoint rather than the whole list.

Comment: @Jon, see my update, I create another extension so that the contact points can be reused (and re-projected to another class)

Comment: Thanks. that's great worked like a charm.. I have edited your answer to show a helper we wrote to wrap it up a little more if anyone else comes across this.  Thanks again

Comment: @Jon, feel free to improve it, in case you find similar problem, you can write a normal linq query, then see the generated expression using [expression tree visualizer](http://exprtreevisualizer.codeplex.com), all you need to do just reverse engineering the expression

Comment: Good answer, the note about expression tree visualizer is also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using the extension method with Linq-to-entites is bit tricky, since not all providers can understand and translate to corresponding backend call. A relatively safer bet is to take an `IQueryable` and return an `IQueryable` which it can resolve:

```
public static IQueryable<SiteDTO> MapToSiteDTO(this IQueryable<Site> query)
{
    return query.Select(s => new SiteLabelDto
                            {
                                Id = s.Id,
                                Name = s.Name,                    
                                Address = s.Address.StreetAddress + ", " + s.Address.Locality + ", " + s.Address.Region + ", " + s.Address.Postcode,
                                Country = s.Address.Country.Name,
                                Email = s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Email) != null ? s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Email).Value : "",
                                Phone = s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Phone) != null ? s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Phone).Value : "",                    
                            });
}
```

And then you call it like:

```
return Context.Sites.Where(s => !s.IsDeleted && s.Vendor.Id == vendorId)
          .Select(x => x)
          .MapToSiteDTO()
          .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Mrchief, it all compiles but I get:  INQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetContactPoint(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Opus.Repository.Models.ContactPointEntity], Opus.Repository.Models.ContactPointType)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: also think there is a typo up to, you are checking src is null.  i think you meant point.. didnt correct just incase I am miss understanding it.  Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer. If you're trying to de-dup your mapping code, then this approach will be just fine. Or if you're looking for a generic way to eliminate the ContactPointType lookup in here as well as other queries, then you may have to tweak this.

Comment: Thanks Mrchief, I am aiming to control the way the contactpoints come out in various places across the domain and across many different POCO's, rather than just one class type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SiteLabelDto[] GetVendorSites(int vendorId)
{
    return (from s in Context.Sites
         where !s.IsDeleted && s.Vendor.Id == vendorId
         let email = s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Email) 
         let phone = s.ContactPoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ContactPointType.Phone)
        select new SiteLabelDto
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Name = s.Name,                    
            Address = s.Address.StreetAddress + ", " + s.Address.Locality + ", " + s.Address.Region + ", " + s.Address.Postcode,
            Country = s.Address.Country.Name,
            Email = email  != null ? email.Value : "",
            Phone = phone != null ? phone .Value : "",
        }).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi James, I am aiming to control the way the contactpoints come out in various places across the domain and across many different POCO's, rather than explicitly using it as described above as would need to rewrite that code lots of times.  Regards